# Exclude moved column order from QHeaderView saveState/restoreState

Tags: qt, savestate, qheaderview

I have a problem with saveState/restoreState of **QHeaderView**. I have several **QTableViews** in my application. The QTableView saves and restores it's QHeaderView settings, but for some QTableViews i'd like to exclude the moved section order from beeing saved to the ini-file.

This means, *saveState* should save sorted column, sort indicator, column width but not if a user has moved a column.

Is there a way to not save the moved columns?

Thank you.

Regards,
Mani

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do this. I suggest something like next:

Use vector to store `logicalIndexes` of moved headers.

```
QVector<int> last;
```

Use `sectionMoved` signal to detect moving and store  `logicalIndex` in vector:

```
connect( ui->tableView->horizontalHeader(),static_cast<void (QHeaderView::*)(int,int,int)>(&QHeaderView::sectionMoved),[=](int logicalIndex, int oldVisualIndex, int newVisualIndex)
{//with lambda
    //you can also provide shecking is current logicalIdnex already exist in vector
    last.push_back(logicalIndex);
 });
```

Syntax is so complicate and ugly because there is another `sectionMoved` in `QHeaderView`, so it is necessary. If you don't know new syntax, use old:

```
connect( ui->tableView->horizontalHeader(), SIGNAL(sectionMoved(int,int,int)), this, SLOT(yourSlot(int,int,int)));
```

But create `yourSlot(int,int,int)` and do `last.push_back(logicalIndex);` in this slot.

When you want `saveState`, hide all sections with `logicalIndex` which you store in vector and save it:

```
QByteArray array;
for(int i = 0; i < last.size(); i++)
{
    ui->tableView->horizontalHeader()->hideSection(last.at(i));
}
array = ui->tableView->horizontalHeader()->saveState();
```

Add `CONFIG += c++11` to the pro file if you want use new syntax and lambda.